# Separation of linear forms

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-approximation

Let $r\ge5$ and $0<x_1<x_2<\dots<x_{r-1}<x_r<1$ be independent over $\mathbb Q$. Fix some $N\ge 5$ and consider the linear forms
$$
f({\bf a})=\sum_{i=1}^r a_i x_i,\quad {\bf a}\in \{0,1,\dots,N\}^r,
$$ 
where ${\bf a}=(a_1,\dots, a_r)$.

**Question.** What is known about
$$
\min\{ |f({\bf a})-f({\bf b})| : {\bf a}\neq{\bf b}\}?
$$
More specifically, if we were free to choose $x_1,\dots, x_r$ as we please (given $r$), how should be do it in such a way that this minimum would be as large as possible? ("maximum separation")

Comment: Schmidt, Diophantine Approximation, SLNM 785 (1980), Ch. 4 section 2.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this, Felipe? I have a Russian copy and am not sure the numeration is the same. Thanks.

Comment: The section that discusses badly approximable systems of linear forms.

Comment: Oops, sorry. Yes, ch 2 sect. 4.

Comment: @Felipe Voloch, I have no access to the Schmidt book. Could you summarize the main result in an answer please?

Comment: @kodlu I can see it on google books https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=XqZtCQAAQBAJ&pg=PR9&source=gbs_selected_pages&cad=2#v=onepage&q&f=false